# WCF + MVC + WebAPI handlers and routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I recently upgraded Visual Studio to 2013 which now only uses IIS Express by default (instead of Cassini) and found I could no longer hit my WCF service javascript endpoints: Myservice.svc/js or /jsdebug, but hitting the .svc directly would work fine.

I've found that if I remove the <handlers> section of my web.config (which includes some ExtensionlessUrlHandler items), the functionality to the script endpoints is restored. I'm curious what repercussions removing the following items would have, and if there is an alternative solution.

Here is the block I removed from my Web.config:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Some context, I'm using .NET 4.5, MVC 5.1, WebAPI v2.1 and WCF all in one project. Essentially the newest versions of all the components.

**Update 1:**
I'm also noticing that any WebAPI PUT's are coming back as a 404 with these handlers removed; so something is obviously missing. The other minor epiphany, is that when deployed to a live server (IIS 7.5  [Version 7.5.7600.16385]) everything works great. So there has to be a difference in the routing or handler mappings of the Visual Studio 2013 integrated version of IIS Express and a full IIS 7.5 setup.

ALSO, If I create a brand new ASP.NET web app and add a WCF service, everything works fine locally. If I then add in a WebAPI controller, the handlers section below is added to the web.config and breaks all the WCF calls. This makes it sound more like a 'bug' in Microsoft's  default configuration when MVC, WCF, and WebAPI are all a part of one application.

**Update 2:**
Here's a basic test case anyone can follow to reproduce the error I'm having.

*Process to recreate base issue:*
(WebAPI working, WCF *.svc/js results in 404)

1. New Project -> Asp.NET Web Application, using Web API Template (includes MVC and Web API references)
2. Add new "WCF Service (ajax-enabled) to project root named "TestService"
3. Start project.
4. Verify that /help route works for MVC (renders help page)
5. Verify that GET /api/values/1 works for WebApi (returns value)
6. *** Verify that PUT /api/values/1 works for WebApi (returns nothing - void method) ***
7. Verify TestService.svc can be hit for WCF (shows metadata page)
8. *** Verify that TestService.svc/js FAILS with a 404 for WCF - Routing issue! ***

*Partial Fix:*
(WebAPI PUT broken, WCF can render JS request)

1. Continue from above...
2. Update Web.config and comment out <handlers> section
3. Start project.
4. Verify that /help route works for MVC (renders help page)
5. Verify that GET /api/values/1 works for WebApi (returns value)
6. *** Verify that PUT /api/values/1 FAILS with a 404 for WebApi - Routing issue! ***
7. Verify TestService.svc can be hit for WCF (shows metadata page)
8. *** Verify that TestService.svc/js renders necessary JavaScript for WCF ***

Comment: IIS Express doesn't really perform a proper reproduction of IIS behavior, nor does it offer many benefits over the alternatives. What happens using the ASP.NET Development Server?

Comment: I'm not using a separate install of IIS Express, just the one that Visual Studio installed/runs by default.

Comment: I understand, but you can change that in your project's properties.

Comment: These are the VS2013 options: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38264/vs2013-webservers.png

Comment: Oh my, they've really crippled that one. Look, IIS Express has its quirks, but if you remove the handlers and it works then, why don't you leave it at that?

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this? I'm getting 404 on PUT operations when creating the unholy trifecta of WebForms, MVC and WebAPI, but POST operations seem to be going OK

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a mvc routing issue.  Please modify your ~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs as below.  You need to keep the ExtensionlessUrlHandler in order for mvc routing to function normally on extensionless urls.

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //This line is the addition.
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.svc/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I actually have that line right at the start of my RouteConfig, and with the handlers in place my *.svc/js are still 404ing. Also, with the handlers removed, I'm also noticing that any WebAPI PUT's are coming back as a 404; so I guess you're correct in that something is missing.

Comment: Can you post an example of your usage of web api.  Are you using attribute routing?  I'm trying to repro your situation.  Based on the first edit to your question I added a web api controller with a simple get method and everything still works for me.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth - I added "Update 2" above with the exact steps I used on an empty project to recreate my issue". I'm using Windows 8.1 and Visual Studio 2013 with the built in IIS Express, and just the steps indicated.